# dask.distributed error can I use Dask.config instead?

Tags: parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to implement Dask and mpi4py. I was wondering what is the difference between these 2 code segments.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers=6)

dask.config.set(scheduler='threads')
dask.config.set(num_workers=6)
```

My code works fine when I use dask.config but when I use dask.distrubuted it goes in to loop with distrubuted nanny error. so my question is are these two  code segments interchangeable. And if I use 2nd code segment in my code is it actually using 6 workers to execute the code.

Any insights about these will be really helpful.
Thank you.

Any insights about dask.distributed and dask.config. i looking to learn more about implementing dask and mpi.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Client`, dask starts new processes for the workers, as well as a separate scheduler process. Because this re-imports the code here, it in turn also tries to start new clusters, causing the error. You must, therefore, protect your `Client` call inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

For other differences between the threaded scheduler and distributed in general, please read the documentation. Both have their uses.